# Footer relative is not always at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am building a website with a relative footer (first picture) but as you can see the footer is not placed at the bottom when there is not enough content on the page.

I could resolve it with position absolute but then the content of the page is hidden behind the footer (picture 2).

**My question**

How can I put the footer on the bottom of the page but still push it down when there is more content added to the page.

[image]

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you share your HTML (i.e. the front end part)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `position: fixed; bottom:0;` for the footer and it is always at the bottom of your screen.

Comment: If you still have problem with overlaping content over footer, you can set `z-index` of footer greater than content of page. You can use `z-index: 100` if you didn't touch any z-index on other elements